# Can't get an image to move to the left in a division?

Tags: html, css

## Context and example

For context, I just recently started coding to make a website as a project I've wanted to do. Right now I have a placeholder image that when clicked is supposed to send you back to the main part of the site but I cant get the image to move away from the text its in a `<div>` with

Currently what the site looks like:

[image: Currently what the site looks like]

I tried so far to use css to make the margin or padding on the text block to push the image away But the image itself wont budge but I can put padding on the image and it pushes the text away.
Sending below the code I currently have with html and css

This is what I want the top to look like:

[image: This is what I want the top to look like]

```css
.intpage {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

.Image {
  float: left;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
}

body {
  background-color: #c78df7;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', "Lucida Console", monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="intpage">
  <div class="Image">
    <a href="https://aechcreations.github.io"><img src="Imagess/pholdr.png" alt="placeholder" width="132" height="132" onmouseover="this.src='Imagess/pholdr2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Imagess/pholdr.png'" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="Text">
    <h1> testing </h1>
  </div>
</div>

<p> this is a test that I think is working </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As the class `.intpage` 's display property is flex, you don't need to make the image `float:left`. remove `float:left`
2. The classes `.Image` and `.Text` should be made into percentage as you want `h1` to be centered (Note: The class name given in css is `.test` and the class name given in html is `Test`. Class names  are case sensitive)
3. For the image provide only width and mention height as `auto`
4. Add `align = "center"` in the img tag as the img tag is a child of the class `.Image`
5. For the sake of understanding, Font-size of `.Test`, I've reduced to 30px.
6. Remove `float:left` in the class `.Test`. The `text-align:center` will conflict to `float:left`. If you want this to be in left change `text-align:center` to `text-align:left`
7. `h1` will be in the center of the right side portion (85%), and `<p>` will be in the center of the whole screen width. This may make you to think that it is not properly aligned. So, for you to understand, I'have added a line separating two divisions. To remove this remove `<hr size="3" color="white">` from html.

Checked with a dummy image. [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/L0DsxYJ)

Placed the css between  tag. You can remove and paste into separate css file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Aech Vee Creations</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="Imagess/favicontest.png">
    <style>
    


.intpage {
    display: flex;
    }

.Image{
    
    width : 12%;
    margin: 0 10px;

}

.Text{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 70px;
    width:85%;
    color: #ffffff;
    }

body{
    background-color: #c78df7;
    }
    

p{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Lucida Console', "Lucida Console", monospace;
    }
    
    
  
    </style>
    
    
    </head>
<body>
<div class = "intpage">
<div class = "Image">
<a href="https://aechcreations.github.io"><img src="https://imgur.com/a/L0DsxYJ" alt="placeholder" width="132" height="auto" align="center"
    onmouseover="this.src='Imagess/pholdr2.png'"
    onmouseout="this.src='Imagess/pholdr.png'" />
</a>
</div>
<div class = "Text">
    <h1> testing </h1> 
</div>

</div>
<hr size="3" color="white">

    <p> this is a test that I think is working </p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your content to be inline you need to wrap it in a div and use display: flex and flex-direction:row (if you use column (.intpage) it  will stack child elements verticaly). Check this code hope it helps

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-inline: 5px;
}
.intpage {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}


body{
    background-color: #c78df7;
    }
    

p{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Lucida Console', "Lucida Console", monospace;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class = "intpage">
            <div class = "Image">
                <a href="https://aechcreations.github.io"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="placeholder" width="132" height="132"
                    onmouseover="this.src='https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale'"
                    onmouseout="this.src='https://picsum.photos/200/300/?blur=2'" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class = "Text">
                <h1> image description </h1> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1>Example Header</h1>
        <div class = "Image">
            <a href="https://aechcreations.github.io"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/870/200/300?grayscale&blur=2" alt="placeholder" width="132" height="132">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p> This is a test that I think is working </p>
```